# Ubuntu 9.04 to 9.10 partial upgrade broke my mouse!

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, upgrade, touchpad

I upgraded Ubuntu 9.04 to 9.10, then I stopped it in the middle and then did a partial upgrade later. Now, when I boot, there is a"ghost" of the animated loading bar (aka: messed up drivers) and the mouse WON'T move. This is an HP Pavillion dv2500 series (model #2650) laptop.

Edit: Mouse Works - next problem - [wlan driver...](https://superuser.com/questions/81750/ubuntu-wireless-driver-reinstall)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop to a terminal and run `cat /dev/psaux` OR `cat /dev/mouse/0` and move the mouse around. If you see a bunch of data dump to the screen, that proves that the mouse is working. You can end the horrible dump by pressing Control-C.

Next, you need to make sure that /etc/X11/xorg.conf has the correct driver and points to the correct device node (/dev/psaux or /dev/mouse/0).

If that still does not work, you may be dealing with HAL messing up when attempting to autodetect the devices.

Add/update the "ServerFlags" section in xorg.conf with:

```
sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf


Section "ServerFlags"
    Option "AutoAddDevices" "False"
    Option "AllowEmptyInput" "False"
EndSection
```

Close out by holding Control and Pressing X. Follow the prompts to overwrite.

Also, you may need to make sure that the following packages have been installed/updated using apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-kbd xserver-xorg-input-mouse
```

Comment: OK, determined mouse, see above - how do I edit xorg.conf?

Comment: I just edited my answer. Look above.

Comment: I think the packages are corrupt. How can I connect to the internet via command line?

Comment: Fixed the mouse. +1